# Memory leas when upgrading to Visual Studio 2019

Tags: memory-leaks, visual-studio-2019, upgrade

I recently upgraded our projects from VS2010 to 2019 which works pretty well, but hen runningit under the Debugger I get a lot of memoryleaks on finish.
Of course they where not there in VS2010.
All of my sources are build with

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif
```

But the dump of the leaks kinda looks like this:

```
[16300] Detected memory leaks!
[16300] Dumping objects ->
[16300] {64582} 
[16300] normal block at 0x06210D00, 16 bytes long.
[16300]  Data: <   z   z        > FC 8B AD 7A 18 8C AD 7A 01 00 00 00 80 DC 1C 06 
[16300] {64581} 
[16300] normal block at 0x06210E00, 16 bytes long.
[16300]  Data: <   z   z    0   > FC 8B AD 7A 18 8C AD 7A 01 00 00 00 30 D5 1C 06 
[16300] {64580} 
[16300] normal block at 0x062109C0, 16 bytes long.
[16300]  Data: <   z   z        > FC 8B AD 7A 18 8C AD 7A 01 00 00 00 E8 CB 1C 06 
[16300] {64579} 
[16300] normal block at 0x06210780, 16 bytes long.
[16300]  Data: <   z   z        > FC 8B AD 7A 18 8C AD 7A 01 00 00 00 90 C6 1C 06
```

This continues for about 5700 mor lines ;-(

I already checked memory- and handle-consumtion: both are ok.
I tried to use tools like MemPro (says no leaks), Dr. Memory (crashes) and Visual leak detector, which says

```
[16300] No memory leaks detected.
[16300] Visual Leak Detector is now exiting.
```

after the leaks-dump ...

Is it likly that I had the leaks in VS2010 already but they where not found/reportet? I don't think so?

So are there any hints to start searching for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DeLeaker did the trick and helped my finding the Leaks. After all I found some .cpp-files, that had NOT set `#define new DEBUG_NEW`. After fixing that, finding the problem was quite easy. Thank you for your help, Artem Razin

Answer (score 1):

> Is it likly that I had the leaks in VS2010 already but they where not
> found/reportet? I don't think so?
>
> So are there any hints to start searching for it?

Since **VS2017**, VS has a decent memory analysis tool which can be used to find memory leaks.

When you debug your project in VS2019(remember to set a breakpoint), open **Debug** --> **Windows** --> **Show Diagnostic Tools**--> pick **memory usage**

**Then** debug the code, when the breakpoint is hit, click **Take snapshot** on the M**emory Usage** window.

**After that**, you can click on the icon to enter into the analysis of the memory and you can find the problem.

[image]

You can also refer to [one official document](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/analyze-cpu-memory-while-debugging/) and [two official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2019) to get the tips.

=========================================

**Besides**,you can also [use the CRT library to find memory leaks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/finding-memory-leaks-using-the-crt-library?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but es, I've noticed this window already but it doesn't seem to help me here. Of course I can see mememory changes and consumptions at runtime but these are no leaks, they all get freed when I close the app so I don't know what snapshots I should compare to another

Comment: @suriel try another profiler like Deleaker to double-check. Also, may it happen that CRT outputs leak information before the memory freed (global objects?).